# method titleForRow for UIPicker is not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

i want to use a UIPickerView in my project, but my titleForRow method is not being called even though numberOfComponentsInPickerView and numberOfRowsInComponent are called. Does anyone knows what to do with it?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return pickerData.count;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *title = [pickerData objectAtIndex:row];
    return title;
}
```

These are my UIPickerView methods and i have set dataSource and delegate like this:

```
self.schedulePicker.dataSource = self;
self.schedulePicker.dataSource = self;
```

I am working in Xcode 6.1.1 but the deployment target is 7.1.

Thanks anyone for help.

Comment: `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` is a `UIPickerViewDelegate` method, not a `UIPickerViewDataSource` Method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the `UIPickerViewDatasource` twice rather than setting the `UIPickerViewDelegate`.

Change to:

```
self.schedulePicker.dataSource = self;
self.schedulePicker.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Yes, that`s it! How could i missed that? Thank you so much!